# Missing Compiled line indicator in new RIO version

Tags: delphi

After changing to Delphi 10.3 Rio, the blue dots, indicating an executable line in the editor do not appear.  I have searched for a new option for this, but can't find one.  I have also searched and can't find any complaints about this.

Does anyone else see this?

Comment: This isn't a very helpful question. You ask, "Does anyone else see this?". Possible answers are yes and no. Submit a bug report to Embarcadero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is not Rio's problem:
Look at `Project configuration` window (usually right top)
Set `Build configuration` to **Debug**  (should become bold)
Recompile or build project (Project menu or Ctrl/Shift - F9)

Comment: Sorry for the badly formed question.  It was as MBo said.  10.2 didn't care and would show in either mode.  10.3 obviously cares.

Comment: @SysJames It seems for me that such behavior stays the same for many versions - from the moment when `Build configuration` was introduced.

Comment: The behaviour of the program has not changed at all.

Comment: Then I apologize.  I must be confused on the issue.  Thank you for the correction.